# Copy records of one year to another year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have three tables, State, City, and Village.

```
State   (PK_Id,Name,Year)
City    (PK_Id,Name,FK_StateId)
Village (PK_Id,Name,Year,FK_CityId)
```

PK means primary key and FK is foreign key. I want to copy every state of last year to new year, and every city of last year, and every village of last year.

Is it possible? How can I do it? It is really harder than it seems.

**Update**:
The problem appears when I  want to copy cities of last year to a new year. And it seems really impossible when I decide to copy villages of last year to new year.

Comment: can't you update the year?. need more clarity on your question.

Comment: Do you have a problem with selecting proper `FK_StateId` values when inserting new `City` rows?

Comment: yes and for villages i have this problem too\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO State (Name, Year)
SELECT S.Name, 2011
FROM State S
WHERE S.Year = 2010

INSERT INTO City (Name, FK_StateId)
SELECT C.Name, S_new.PK_Id
FROM City C
INNER JOIN State S_old ON C.FK_StateId = S_old.PK_Id
  AND S_old.Year = 2010
INNER JOIN State S_new ON S_old.Name = S_new.Name
  AND S_new.Year = 2011

INSERT INTO Village (Name, Year, FK_CityId)
SELECT V.Name, 2011, C_new.PK_Id
FROM Village V
INNER JOIN City C_old ON C.FK_CityId = C_old.PK_Id
  AND C_old.Year = 2010
INNER JOIN City C_new ON C_old.Name = C_new.Name
  AND C_new.Year = 2011
```

Comment: All of primary keys are Identity.

Answer (score -1):

You can use temporary tables to store a copy of the 3 tables. Update the year in all temp tables and then insert back into main tables.

Comment: No no , When I insert a copy of last year village to the table villages related to cities of last year .but they must relate to cities of new year .

Comment: Do you need clone/copy villages and cities as well?